# Is it possible to get the device sizes in flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am building a flutter web app, and I would like to know the width of the device the app is running on, not the window. Is this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it without access to `BuildContext` like this:

```
final double width = window.physicalSize.width / window.devicePixelRatio;
final double height = window.physicalSize.height / window.devicePixelRatio;
```

Make sure you import `dart:ui`, not the html library.

Comment: This does the same as MediaQuery.of(context).size

Comment: Bennett567 indeed it does, but it does not require buildcontext, so it can be called outside of widget tree.